# How to link to Libtooling with cmake

Tags: cmake, dynamic-linking, libtooling

According to [docs](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibTooling.html#linking), I have following cmake project

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(teeest LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(LLVM REQUIRED)
find_package(Clang REQUIRED)


add_executable(teeest main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(teeest
    PRIVATE
    clangAST
    clangFrontend
    clangTooling
)
```

but when I try to build the project, I get follwing error

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lclangAST
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lclangFrontend
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lclangTooling
```

I have install [llvm](https://archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/llvm/) package from archlinux's repository

Comment: The usage of `find_package` described here is a bit different to yours: https://llvm.org/docs/CMake.html#embedding-llvm-in-your-project does the linked approach work for you?

Comment: @fabian, I tried putting different text versions of `libtooling` in  `llvm_map_components_to_libnames` but its not working

Comment: Might be a duplicate or at least helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8774593/2799037

Answer (score 0):

Following helped me resolve the error:

```
find_package( LLVM  REQUIRED CONFIG )
find_package( Clang REQUIRED CONFIG )
```